# How to use multiple while loops at the same time?

Tags: c, while-loop

Say in a video game, I need to have two while loops listening at the same time, one to:

```
while (up == true)
    movePlayerX(2)
```

and the other to:

```
while (right == true)
    movePlayerY(2)
```

How would I get the player to move up and right at the same time if:

```
int main()
{

while(1)
    printf("hello");

while(1)
    printf("world");

    return(0);
}
```

Would only ever return "hello"? Is it possible to have the 2 while loops working at the same time or do they have to take turns? I know at assembly level they have to take turns but for high level programming:

```
while(1)
{
    while( up == true)
            movePlayerX(2)
            break;
    while( right == true)
            movePlayerY(2)
            break;
}
```

What about this situation:

```
while(1)
    answer = promptUserForData();                     //user enters data at their own pace
    chart = addAnswerToChart(answer);                 //char is updated when user updates it

while(1)
    chart = someOtherDataThatEffectsChart(randData);  //something else effects the chart

while(1)
    printOutChart(chart);                             //chart is constantly being printed out
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `while (1) { if (up) movePlayerX(2); if (right) movePlayerY(2); }`

Comment: i think you posted that before my first edit but anyway i think your answer is more elegant then my 4th block of code but still equivalent. I'm more trying to figure out how i can update data that gets input into another program while collecting data form another source and prompting the user for input.

Comment: Oh, well now I see your new edit. Yes, now I think it's equivalent, although a bit odd to `break` from the `while` loop instead of just using `if`.

Comment: yeah i agree bad use of a while - break. Any way i'm think i would need two separate executables  and a file to accomplish the last bit because no matter how i figure ill stall my program with user input. How do video games say update the AIs & environment while still listening for while (1) { if (up) movePlayerX(2); if (right) movePlayerY(2); }

Answer (score 2):

For you question about multiple whiles running at the same, the only way I see it would work is on multiple paralel threads, which in your case has no reason to, because you instead should restructure your code to work smarter.

I have no idea how you have your game set up, but the best way would be to execute the game logic in an infinite loop in steps.
Instead of asking while (up), your loop should look something like this:

```
void mainGameLoop () {
   while (!gameQuit) {
      handleInput();
      handleLogic(); 
      handleDrawing();
}
```

This way, every loop of the game you first handle the input events (like keyboard press or mouse click/move), than the logic of the game and than draw it to the screen.

For the player movement there are many approaches but what I would suggest is and X/Y acceleration model. The way it works, is that the player object has an xSpeed and ySpeed variable which tells the speed at which he is moving in that direction. For the movement then what you would do is if the movement key is pressed you increment (or decrement if the movement is in the negative direction) the axis speed or until it reaches the speed you want to be the max speed.

Then in the logic you simply add a friction that slows down the player, so if the movement keys aren't being pressed the player stops after a few loops.

Finally to move the player you simmply add the xSpeed and ySpeed to his position.

Very simple implementation would look like this. I will be using some pseudo functions that represent the input handling.

```
void handleInput() {
   if (keyPressed)
      switch(key) {
         case upArrow: 
            ySpeed -= 0.1;
            break;
         case downArrow: 
            ySpeed += 0.1;
            break;
         case leftArrow: 
            ySpeed -= 0.1;
            break;
         case rightArrow: 
            ySpeed += 0.1;
            break;
      }
}

void handleLogic() {
   // Clamp speed values to maximum of |1| speed
   if (ySpeed > 1)
       ySpeed = 1;
   if (ySpeed < -1)
       ySpeed = -1;
   if (xSpeed > 1)
       xSpeed = 1;
   if (xSpeed < -1)
       xSpeed = -1;

   // Friction slowing down the movement if no movement keys are pressed
   if (ySpeed > 0)
      ySpeed -= 0.05;
   else if (ySpeed < 0)
      ySpeed += 0.05;

   if (xSpeed > 0)
      xSpeed -= 0.05;
   else if (xSpeed > 0)
      xSpeed -= 0.05;

   xPosition += xSpeed;
   yPosition += ySpeed;
}
```

Values are purely for the example here. You can experiment with them around a bit to get the handling of the character you want.

Comment: thanks a ton for the response. I was trying to be general but the game just was a example, I'm building a graphical representation of the banker algorithm. One window will have a live graph of the system resources, the other will prompt for user input.  A idea i got from your response: i could have the user input be a separate program that writes to a file (or threads (i havn't really learned threads yet so i guess thats my night) then the function you said "handleInput()" could just listen to the file or handle the thread. thanks again.